# Using multiple ultrasonic sensors simultanously with the same trigger

Tags: sensors

I want to use three ultrasonic sensors together and would prefer to use as few pins as possible, so I was thinking of using one trigger for all 3 sensors. The sensors will have an angle of 90 degrees between them. I was wondering if this would still cause false readings? Since they are a large angle (and some distance) apart?

Comment: I think this isn't really answerable, since it greatly depends on your environment. You might get stray reflections into the other sensors. I suggest you just try it out.

Comment: If you're using the usual HC-SR04 sensor you should check if there's an ECHO pulse without a prior TRIG pulse output at all. (Otherwise, you can feed all TRIG pins from the same Arduino OUTPUT pin). And keep in mind that `pulseIn` blocks, so you cannot use it to  get multiple more or less simultaneous signals.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this a while back using HC-SR04 sensors and did have some issues with bad (well, strange) readings. but I was just fiddling around with it and haven't gone back to it.

That being said, if you connect the triggers together, but the echo lines individually, and put at least 60ms delay between triggering and reading each sensor, then it might work for your application.

This thread briefly touches on how the time it takes for a ping to decay is part of the issue.
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/multiple-ultrasonic-sensors-close-together/410358

My understanding of it suggests that if you send out a ping in multiple directions, the ping going right echoes off a surface, then echoes off a surface on the left side, which returns to the sensor on the other side, so the sensor might receive a lot of noise.

The datasheet on the HC-SR04 indicates that the cycle time of a single measurement should be 60ms, so a trigger signal doesn't align with an echo...
https://forum.arduino.cc/uploads/short-url/961oW5W0LoHZ6t5XOP40HryBlZK.pdf

In any case, these sensors are cheap and I find that throwing a few bits on a proto board and testing experimenting with them is the best way to learn.

Start with two sensors opposing each other with a surface at 2 inches in front of one, and at 4 inches from the other. trigger them together, see if you can get a clean read from either one. Experiment with different distances to objects (like within an inch on each side, etc). Then repeat the process with a third at the front, and with surface objects at odd angles.

I hope this is helpful, if not encouraging at least :)